# usage of LIMIT option in SELECT ... BULK COLLECT INTO

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulk-collect

Starting from the answer of this question ([Use Bulk Collect result in a select query without cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755784/use-bulk-collect-result-in-a-select-query-without-cursor)), I am wondering if it is possible to use the LIMIT option in SELECT ... BULK COLLECT INTO ...

I know the possibility to use an explicit cursor but I would like to know if it is possible using a direct select statement.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-9E6FC4CF-A6B7-4C79-996D-50FF22AD3A9D):

> A `SELECT BULK COLLECT INTO` statement that returns a large number of rows produces a large collection. To limit the number of rows and the collection size, use one of these:
>
> - `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn (described in Oracle Database SQL Language Reference)
> - `SAMPLE` clause (described in Oracle Database SQL Language Reference)
> - `FETCH FIRST` clause (described in Oracle Database SQL Language Reference)

So from the example in the previous question you linked to, you could do:

```
SELECT id BULK COLLECT INTO result_bulk FROM table1 WHERE rownum <= 1000;
```

or if you're on 12c:

```
SELECT id BULK COLLECT INTO result_bulk FROM table1 FETCH FIRST 1000 ROWS ONLY;
```

possibly with an order-by (in a subquery in the first version) for it to be deterministic.

The advantage of the explicit `fetch` version with the `limit` clause is that you can do that in a loop and keep fetching the next 1000 (or however many) rows until you've seen them all. With the `select` version you only get one shot; unless you put that in a loop and handle paging, and even then as each `select` is independent the data could change between queries (unless you also change the isolation level).

Comment: Specifying a BULK COLLECT INTO ... LIMIT clause is one of the few good reasons to use an explicit cursor.